# Monitor Artifactory for new artifacts and send the artifact properties to an API

Tags: python, artifactory, python-watchdog

How to send file properties to an API when a new file is pushed to an artifactory ? I am using artifactory6.2 and it does not support Webhooks. Will Python Watchdog help me monitor for new file creation in artifactory?

Comment: What is your CI server?

Comment: It is hosted on AWS Ec2

Answer (score 2):

You can try the user plugins Artifactory feature.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins

In high level, there are events in the system that you can catch, and basically do anything you want, like firing an API, which is like a 'WebHook' implementation.

You could use the beforeUploadHook, or afterCreate hook.

Here are some examples:
https://github.com/JFrog/artifactory-user-plugins

Here is a specific example of usage on the afterCreate hook:
https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/storage/createCopy/createCopy.groovy